# gvim: add "Close without saving" to tab menu

Tags: vim

When I right click on a tab, I get "Close", "New tab", "Open tab..". Now I'm wondering how can I add "Close without saving" option. Is there any way?

Comment: Agreed, why use vim if you're not going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

This menu is described under `:help tabline-menu`. As there are no instructions how to manipulate it, this seems to be a fixed list. You'd have to modify the source code and compile your own Vim binary to change it.

If you feel properly motivated, you could implement a patch that allows to modify this. There's a precedence: The right mouse button popup menu inside the buffer can indeed be extended, see `:help popup-menu`.